# ios json utf8 post trouble - save special character (æ ø å)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa, special-characters

In my ios app i use json to communicate with my webserver. When i do a post in my app using special characters as æ ø å the result in the database is Ã† Ã¸ Ã¥.  When i do a post directly in the database and fetch the result æ ø å it works fine. In my Android app it all works fine both ways using json. I hope you can help me - the code is here:

```
//////NSsession
        NSString *noteDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text=%@&rating=%@&tag=%@&barcode=%@&userid=%@",reviewTxt,[self.ratingBar getRatings] ,@"addReview", barcode,uid];
        NSString *noteDateStringEncode = [noteDataString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{

                                                       @"api-key"       : @"API_KEY"

                                                       };

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        request.HTTPBody = [noteDateStringEncode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

        NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization

                                      JSONObjectWithData:data

                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers

                                      error:&error];

            NSInteger success = 0;

            success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

            NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

            if(success == 1)

            {
                NSLog(@"Add review SUCCESS");
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"reviewComplete" sender:self];

            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Add review Failed!" :0];

            }
        }];
        [postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: Try escaping percentage escape encoding instead send data directly.

Comment: I have tried this one witout luck: `//newString = [reviewTxt stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: can you send me service url which you are using?

Comment: Finally I found the error. I was missing `$con->set_charset("utf8");` in my mysql connection but now it do not work on android - when i use æ ø å i get empty space.

Comment: It all comes together - I was missing this statment in my jsonParser on my android  `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));`

Comment: Thank you for your time and thoughts Raman soni.